# Some streams terminated before this command could finish error

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, databricks, gdelt

I am trying to read streaming data into Azure Databricks . This is the code i've been using:
[image]

And its giving me an error saying:

[image]

my Databrick Runtime is : 6.4 Extended Support (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)
and i install the package : com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.17
but i still get the same error